# running ELF 32-bit MSB executable, MIPS, MIPS64 version 1,

Tags: linux, emulation, reverse-engineering, qemu

Running the file command shows:

```
ELF 32-bit MSB  executable, MIPS, MIPS64 version 1, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, BuildID[sha1]=b9720b983cafb2a111bbac302b4ead891019e600, not stripped
```

After reading some posts I have tried to use `qemu` emulator and many others.

I have tried this  https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8829/cross-debugging-for-mips-elf-with-qemu-toolchain

but when I try to run the file I get:

```
/lib/ld.so.1: No such file or directory.
```

Comment: Take a look at https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=ld.so.1 , I'm guessing you want https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libc6-mips64-cross . I'm also guessing that you're using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dynamically linked binary, so you need not just the ELF file itself, but also the MIPS dynamic linker (this is the ld.so.1 it is asking for) and all the MIPS ELF libraries that the binary links against, and they need to be somewhere where QEMU can find them when the guest binary asks for them. You may be able to do that with Ubuntu/Debian multiarch cross library packages (as the answer you linked suggests), or by setting up a chroot for your guest architecture and running QEMU inside it, or by using QEMU's -L option to give it a path specifying a sysroot where there are guest libraries.